# might be like vs. might have been like

Tags: modal-verbs

I read [this](http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/magazine/entertainment/when-i-was-young) and I'm confused about this sentence.

> I loved being able to play the role of somebody, even just for a short time, to try to realise what it might  be like to walk in their shoes.

Why has the writer chosen to use "might be" instead of "might have been"? I think because he is talking about a past possibility he needs "might have been". What's the difference?

Comment: If they are dead or you are wondering about experiencing events that happened at a specific point in the past you'd say "might have been like", if you are curious what their life is currently like you'd say "might be like"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a past-form modal verb the perfect infinitive construction *have* + past participle does not have a perfect meaning; it marks the eventuality as occurring in the past. For instance, *What {might/would/could} be* speaks of something possible now or in the future:

> It **would be** exciting to be a rock star.
>   I would like to know what it **would be** like to be a rock star.

*What {might/would/could} have been* speaks of something possible in the past:

> It **would have been** exciting to be a virtuoso pianist in the 19th century.
>   I would like to know what it ***would have been*** like to be a virtuoso pianist in the 19th century.